# faceing no such method exception when invoking any java.nio methods on linux lubuntu

Tags: java, linux, nio

I'm facing a problem that drives me crazy, I created a java application using netbeans on a windows machine, it contains a plain java class with main method and imports the **java.nio** as follows.

```
package testubonto;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.BufferOverflowException;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(args[0]);
            System.out.println(path.toString());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
        }
    } 
}
```

i tested my application and it runs fine on my windows machine. I built it and produced it's jar file, the problem came when i tried to run this application on my Lubunto machine, I downloaded the jre-7u5.tar.gz, and extracted the folder.
placed the jar file on the root. and when i tried to run the application using terminal by this command.

> /home/user/jre1.7.0_05/bin/java -jar "TestUbonto.jar" /home/user

i got the following exception,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   java.nio.file.Paths.get

what should i do?? :)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I would try JDK 7 instead of JRE 7 as it must be there or it wouldn't compile.

Comment: I compiled the application on the windows machine not on the lubuntu machine

Comment: where did you get the jre? could you try installing openjdk7 from repositories?

Comment: i downloaded the jdk-7-linux-i586.tar.gz from oracle, i extracted it on the Lubuntu machine, tried to run the application using the jdk, but it was no good either, i got the same exception.

Comment: i tried to compile the application on the same Lubuntu machine that i want to run the application on it, after installing jdk 7, i got the following compilation error: TestLubuntu.java:8: error: cannot find symbol java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.getPath(args[0]); ^ symbol: method getPath(String) location: class Paths 1 error I know that the library doesn't exist, but all i used was java.nio, i dunno where to find this jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NoSuchMethodException occurs when the jar file used for building differs from the one used for executing.

The jar used for building , supplies the method that is required by your code. So there wont be any compilation error and the binary is prepared correctly.

But when you run the same code by giving a wrong version the same jar in the classpath, it will give the above exception.

Verify the jars you are using .

Comment: Just use the same jar file. I mean same physical file not just the file with same name.

Comment: do you know where to get this file?

Comment: This is not a specific problem. This is a generic problem. See which method is showing exception. Find the jar that is having the method. Copy the jar used when compiling, Use the same while executing

Comment: i tried to compile the application on the same Lubuntu machine that i want to run the application on it, after installing jdk 7, i got the following compilation error:

TestLubuntu.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
   java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.getPath(args[0]);
                                                ^
  symbol:   method getPath(String)
  location: class Paths
1 error
I know that the library doesn't exist, but all i used was java.nio, i dunno where to find this jar.

Comment: thank you for your help, i managed to compile the same code after installing jdk 7 on the Lubuntu machine, and it run successfully.